# MS Server DNS Policy for Conditional Forwarder?

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have DCs sitting at campuses that hold my domain, which is separate from the campuses' domain.
I have a few sites that use my DCs at their site for AD. For them to find the domain there is a conditional forwarder. As such, if they try to go to a resource I have defined in DNS, they get my internal IP address. This being unroutable causes problems.

The addresses that need AD are few so I want to set a policy for the others to go to the external server rather than the internal server.

Currently, the conditional forwarder on the sites' DCs point to servers that are 2008 R2. These will be going away as soon as they are virtualized, but I am trying to solve the problem now, hopefully using DNS policies at the lookup on the sites' DCs.

I haven't seen any documentation for this specific case.

Comment: DNS policies do not exist for Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: This is pretty confusing. YourDomain DCs are hosting a conditional forwarder to the CampusDomain zone? But CampusDomain clients are using your DCs for some reason as their primary DNS to resolve CampusDomain? Why are they not using  CampusDomain DCs? If there are no CampusDomain DCs at these sites, getting DNS via YourDomain DCs doesn't provide any benefit - they still have to *authenticate* with their own DCs. They should simply access DNS via the same DCs.